# On the dative of reference

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, dative

If I want to say in Latin *I speak Latin easily*, I say:

> In Latīnā facile loquere possum.

But if I want to add to this the idea that it is in my opinion that I speak Latin easily, do I simply use the dative of reference, like this:

> In Latīnā **tibi** facile loquere possum?

Comment: Just so you know, there are a couple issues with your starting sentence. Perhaps you should also phrase that part as a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by fixing your initial sentence.
My take on translation:

> I can speak Latin easily.
>   *Latine facile loqui possum.*

Important points:

- You speak "Latinly", *Latine*, not "in Latin".
  I do not recall seeing the preposition *in* in this sense in Latin, but I could be mistaken.
  Nevertheless, the adverb (*Latine, Anglice, Germanice…*) is the typical way to express using a language in Latin.
- The verb *loqui* is deponent, so you need to use formally passive forms.
  For example, it is *loquor* instead of *loquo*.

---

Next, I'll offer a completely different alternative.
It is common to express such things with the supine ablative.
My suggestion with an overly literal English translation:

> *Lingua Latina (mihi) facilis est locutu.*
>   Latin language is easy (for me) with respect to speaking.

As brianpck suggested in a comment, this is another good option:

> *Facile est (mihi) Latine loqui.*
>   It is easy (for me) to speak Latin.

---

Finally, let me answer your question.
In English you could add a parenthetical "I think", like this:

> Latin is easy to me, I think.

In Latin, a similar remark could be worded as *credo* (I believe) or *puto* (I think).
The *ut opinor* suggested by Hugh is also a good option, and can be used similarly.

(Also, *tibi* is second person, meaning roughly "to you". Perhaps you meant *mihi*, but that would be weird, too.)

Comment: @brianpck's suggestion is definitely the more common way of saying that. Speed reading, I had to do a double take because I thought *facilis est* was a mistake here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a ready-made phrase, *"ut opinor,"* which, in my opinion, avoids a lot of ambiguities and other problems.

> Suggero 'ut opinor,' quamvis non examussim, ut opinor, tibi respondeo,
>   I suggest *ut opinor,* although I am not, in my opinion, answering you
>   precisely.

Answer (score 3):

If looking for a word meaning 'fluently' we have the authority of Cicero (Brutus, *passim*) himself. Keeping things simple, I suggest:

*lingua latina solute utor*, and

*credo me lingua latina solute uti*.